# When deleting multiple cells at the same time I get a runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I got the follwing code, it works fine when only selecting one cell and deleting it, but when I select multiple cells I get the runtime error 13 "Type mismatch":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim sheetCodeName As String
    Dim cel As Range

    If Target.Column = "12" Then
    On Error GoTo DELETESTUFF
        sheetName = Target.Value
    On Error GoTo 0
        sheetCodeName = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value

        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sheet.CodeName = sheetCodeName Then
            If sheetName = "" Then
                On Error GoTo INVALIDCOLUMNNAME:
            End If
                On Error GoTo INVALIDCOLUMNNAME:
                Sheet.Name = sheetName
                On Error GoTo 0

            End If

        Next Sheet

    End If

Exit Sub

INVALIDCOLUMNNAME:

If Target.Column = "12" Then
    sheetName = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    sheetCodeName = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.CodeName = sheetCodeName Then

            On Error GoTo INVALIDCO:
            Sheet.Name = sheetName
            On Error GoTo 0

        End If

    Next Sheet

End If

Exit Sub

DELETESTUFF:

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(12)) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo INVALIDCO
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cel In Intersect(Target, Columns(12))
        sheetName = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
        sheetCodeName = cel.Offset(0, -2).Value
        For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sheet.CodeName = sheetCodeName Then
                Sheet.Name = sheetName
                Exit For  'no need to continue
            End If
        Next Sheet
    Next cel
End If

Exit Sub

INVALIDCO:
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to happen when you operate on multiple cells? Nothing, or process each one? Also, which event are you using?

Comment: When selecting these multiple cells and hitting the "Delete button", I would like to get the selected cells blank, without the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `Target` and *"deleting"* tells me that this is a `Worksheet_Change` event macro. In those cases, `Target` could represent a range of cells and not just one cell. You need a `For Each ... In Intersect(Target, Columns(12)` to go through each matching cell and perform the action *as it pertains to each cell*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(12)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo INVALIDCO
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Dim cel As Range, sheetName As String, sheetCodeName As String, ws As Worksheet
        For Each cel In Intersect(Target, Columns(12))
            sheetName = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
            sheetCodeName = cel.Offset(0, -2).Value
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.CodeName = sheetCodeName Then
                    If IsEmpty(cel) Then
                        ws.Name = Right("0" & Replace(ws.CodeName, "sheet", vbNullString, 1, 1, vbTextCompare), 2)
                    ElseIf CBool(Len(sheetName)) Then
                        'addition worksheet name validation here
                        ws.Name = sheetName
                    Else
                        'do nothing. blank worksheet name
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ws
        Next cel
    End If
INVALIDCO:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In other words, if you selected L2:L5 and tapped <kbd>Delete</kbd>, then `Target` is equal to L2:L5 and you cannot assign K2:K5 to *sheetName* the way you have in your original code. If you are planning to use this for multiples, additional error control should be added to make sure that there are appropriate values in the J and K columns for each deleted value in column L.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :), I tried it, I seem now to be able to delete multiple cells, but now the sheet names do not change anymore, I edited my post to its full code. I think there might be some errors (I am quite new to VBA).

Comment: @SergeInácio - Your original error control only covered the worksheet renaming operation while mine covers the whole operation. If you have an error assigning the worksheet name to what is in column K, it errors out of the whole process. As I mentioned, error control should be added so that appropriate worksheet names and worksheet code names are in columns J and K.  Sample data together with a description of the desired results would help. BTW, my test workbook *does* change the worksheet name(s).

Comment: My goal is to change the sheets name according to column "L", and if the cell on column "L" is empty to assign a number to it (1 to 10 (got 10 sheets in total)), this part I was able to do. It also works when I delete one by one, the only part where it fails is when I try to delete multiple cells at the same time

Comment: @SergeInácio - please see my revisions above that accommodate the additional requirements.